# How to split an RDD by columns into a list of RDDs in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

Let's say we have this RDD:

```
RDDs = sc.parallelize([["panda", 0], ["pink", 3]])
```

As RDDs has two columns now, want to get two RDDs like this:

```
RDDList[0] = (["panda"], ["pink"])
RDDList[1] = ([0], [3])
```

Couldn't find a discussion on this topic before, is this even feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built on @Ramesh Maharjan answer to get it work for any RDD
(python 3.x)

```
RDDList = []
for i in range(0,len(RDDs.first())):
    RDDList.append(RDDs.map(lambda x: [x[i]]).collect())

print (RDDList[0])
print (RDDList[1])
```

Expected Output:

```
[['panda'], ['pink']]
[[0], [3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
RDDs = sc.parallelize([["panda", 0], ["pink", 3]])

cols = [0, 1]
RDDList = [(RDDs.map(lambda x: [x[col]]).collect()) for col in cols]
```

which should give you

```
print RDDList[0]
#[['panda'], ['pink']]

print RDDList[1]
#[[0], [3]]
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: it works for this case, but need for variable number of colums

Comment: I have edited my answer for the variable number of columns @iBart

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh, I've modified to work dynamically with any RDD

Comment: thats great :) if the answer is helpful then you should consider upvoting it and you can accept it or your answer